# Geometric Median: Is there a Java implementation for Weiszfeld's Algorithm?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, median

I'm trying to calculate the geometric median for a list of 2/3D points. I've already tried different implementations, but I'm still looking for better results.

I wonder if there is a Java implementation for Weiszfeld's Algorithm so I can save some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a java implementation of the Weiszfeld method based on this paper: http://ie.technion.ac.il/Home/Users/becka/Weiszfeld_review-v3.pdf.

The repo is on github: https://github.com/j05u3/weiszfeld-implementation.

Comment: pdf link is dead.

Comment: @SinanKozak This [publication](https://web.iem.technion.ac.il/images/user-files/becka/papers/44.pdf) looks similar up to the section 7.3 but I have not yet finished reading it in detail enough to be completely sure.